# Flutter widget wrapped inside custom widget

Tags: android, flutter, widget, custom-widgets

I have a custom widget named `CustomBox`:

```
class CustomBox extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 30),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
        ),

        //custom child here

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Where I put `custom child here`, I want to put any child inside, but from the widget-tree. See this custom widget is a box (with specific borders and stuff). And I want to be able to blub this into my app whenever and put say an Image or some text (maybe also a row with children) on the inside. How do I do that, without putting the new widget inside this custom widget?

Comment: what is the error you are getting if you are adding child inside custom widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CustomBox extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget childWidget;
  CustomBox({this.childWidget});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 30),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
        ),

        child: this.childWidget,

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Access it through

```
CustomBox(childWidget: Text('Hello'));
```

or

```
CustomBox(childWidget: Row(children: <Widget>[...]));
```

Comment: and by convention it should be named `child`, not `childWidget`

Answer (score 1):

You can `pass your child widget` in a dynamic way via the use of the `constructor`. You can do like this:

```
class CustomBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget childWidget;
  CustomBox(this.childWidget);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
      child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 30, 30, 30),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
          ),
          //custom child here
          child: childWidget),
    );
  }
}
```

and when you need to use, do like this:

`CustomBox(Text('Text'))`. Just replace `Text('Text')` with your choice of widget.